# How to move from end of list, to start in Python's lists?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-2.7, list

How to get the first value of a list, from its last two values.

For example I have a list:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','y','z']
# I know that going from 'a' to 'y' is using negatives,
n = 0 - 2 
list1[n]
# This will give the value of 'y'

# but how do I do the opposite? 'y' to 'a' ?
# not fetching the values from 'y' to 'a', instead, traversing from 'y' to 'a'
```

Comment: Do you mean `list1[-2::-1]` => `['y', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']`?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "from `y` to `a`"; `a` can be fetched with just `list1[0]`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
i = (j + 2) % n
# where j is the index of 'y'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need values from `'y'` to `'a'`:

```
>>> list1[n::-1]
['y', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

`n` - start of the new list, `-1` - step

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. Start of list `-2` and step `-1`

```
li = ['a','b','c','d','y','z']
print(li[-2::-1])
#['y', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```